# Opening a new tab when user clicks on some url in chrome extension

Tags: javascript

I have written a chrome extension. I'd like all urls to open in a new tab when user clicks on it without using target=_blank in onclick, as it would be tedius work for me.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you'd like anyone's help, show what you have done at this point. What have you tried? How did it work? What problems are you facing now? 'Just tell me how to do that' questions aren't appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
  // Check for button click
   if (e.button == 0) { // left click 
      window.open('http://google.com');
  }
   else if (e.button == 3){//right click
      window.open('http://yahoo.com');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you